# How can I add dependencies that must use plugins and classpath?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to make a bundle-library that contains commonly used library. For example, retrofit2, okhttp, hilt, viewmodel, livedata, navigation, room, etc.

And then, I want to just import,

```
dependencies{
    implementation "com.github.my_account:common-library:1.0.0"

    // rest of them...
}
```

Then, the gradle file will look clean.

However, when the libraries that need to add plugin and classpath seems doesn't work.

For example, `hilt` need to do...

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.20'
    ext.hilt_version = '2.33-beta' // THIS

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version" // THIS
        // ...
    }
}

// ..
```

And

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    ...
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin' // THIS
}

// ..

dependencies{
    // ...

    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"
}
```

But when I import `implementation "com.github.my_account:common-library:1.0.0"` in my gradle(module), it doesn't import hilt libraries, so, IDE can't detect any class or annotation from hilt library. So, I added its classpath in gradle.build(project), and plugin in thee plugins of gradle.build(module). But didn't add it in dependencies in it. Then, this message comes up.

```
The Hilt Android Gradle plugin is applied but no com.google.dagger:hilt-android dependency was found.
```

So, what I think of is, if the library needs to write 'classpath' and 'plugin', I am not able to add them in the bundle library.

How can I solve this issue or what's the problem?